# Mysql 1 warning

Tags: mysql

After creating a new mysql non root user and logged in mysql with those credential I get a warning.

I use these commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
CREATE USER db_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

After the third command I get:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Then I type `show warnings;`

```
Warning | 1287 | Using GRANT for creating new user is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Create new user with CREATE USER statement.
```

I already used `CREATE DATABASE db_name;`
I should not get this warning.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to get rid of that warning?

Comment: I think the message is clear: *Using GRANT for creating new user is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Create new user with CREATE USER Statement*

Comment: I you can read all the steps that I posted I have already done that using the second command.

Comment: use `CREATE USER 'db_user'@'localhost'` instead of `CREATE USER db_user;`

Comment: Also it is only a warning

Comment: I have no idea why you think using "CREATE DATABASE" should prevent you being warned about using "GRANT" to create a new user instead of using "CREATE USER" to create a new user.

Answer (score 0):

When using `GRANT ... IDENTIFIED BY ...`, the `IDENTIFIED BY ...` part is what creates the user “inline” with the `GRANT` statement. That is what’s deprecated. You’re supposed to create the user *and their password* separately from granting them privileges. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-overview.